# PHP DOM XML добавить элемент в родителя

Tags: php, xml, dom

я ищу способ добавления элемента  в родительский .
Структура xml документа такова:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
  <article id="1">
    <file>01.jpg</file>
    <title>Фото 1</title>
    <description>Описание 1</description>
  </article>
  <article id="2">
    <file>02.jpg</file>
    <title>Фото 2</title>
    <description>Описание 2</description>
  </article>
...
</content>
```

Уже написана часть кода, но проблем в том, что он добавляет элемент после родительского:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); // DOM
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());

$article = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('article'));
$attr = $article->setAttribute('id', $cnt+1);
$file = $article->appendChild($dom->createElement('file'));
$title = $article->appendChild($dom->createElement('title'));
$description = $article->appendChild($dom->createElement('description'));

$file->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($file_post));
$title->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($title_post));
$description->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($desc_post));

$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно добавить элемент в родительский?
[image: добавить элемент в родительский]

**P.S.** Решение на SimpleXML не писать, это ломает оформление кода!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так... представляю вашему вниманию 2 решения, которые я всё таки смог сделать:

```
/*
$article = $xml->addChild('article'); // SimpleXML
$article->addAttribute('id', $cnt+1);
$article->addChild('file', $file_post);
$article->addChild('title', $title_post);
$article->addChild('description', $desc_post);
*/

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); // DOM

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());

$article = $dom->documentElement->appendChild($dom->createElement('article'));
$attr = $article->setAttribute('id', $cnt+1);
$file = $article->appendChild($dom->createElement('file'));
$title = $article->appendChild($dom->createElement('title'));
$description = $article->appendChild($dom->createElement('description'));

$file->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($file_post));
$title->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($title_post));
$description->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($desc_post));

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Кому нужен SimpleXML - сможет расскомментировать выше запись и закомментировать DOM. Результат:

[image: Правильное решение]